# How to Add .html to the End of a WordPress URL and hide /product-category/

Tags: wordpress

I use the Remove Taxonomy Base Slug plugin to hide in the url /product-category/
For example site.ru/product-category/cars/sport/bmw make site.ru/cars/sport/bmw
the plugin does a good job with it, but it's impossible to add everywhere to the end of the url .html to have site.ru/cars/sport/bmw.html instead of site.ru/product-category/cars/sport/bmw
site.ru/cars.html instead of site.ru/product-category/cars
In the settings of permanent links installed /%postname%.html
but it still does not work, it seems because of the rules of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can hide and show category into URL with `.html` extension into a page. I was developing one plugin for `.html` URL for WordPress. 
check plugin and add your comment. also, we provide support. 
Plugin linn [Wordpress add .htmli into custom post and category list page](https://github.com/jnext-Wp-Plugin/Wordpress-html-into-url-free-plugin)

Sample Code :

```
 function jn_htmlInUrl_page_permalink() {
 global $wp_rewrite;
 if ( in_array( 'page', $this->selected_post_type ) ) {
 if ( ! strpos( $wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.html' ) ) {
     $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.html';
     }
}
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

if you fetching issues and comment here or plugin details page. 
i will try to help resolve issues